# Vue: Should I use "&" or "&amp;" if I am passing in a string as a prop?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a handful of string props I am passing in from a parent component.  Is it best practice to use `&amp;` or `&`?

```
<ChildComponent
    newString="Look & Talk" // or "Look &amp; Talk" ??
>
</ChildComponent>
```

Comment: I would say &amp; would be the way to go since & is a logical operator in javascript

Comment: FYI, your prop attribute should be `new-string`. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Casing-camelCase-vs-kebab-case

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be found in `ChildComponent`:

- the `newString` will be rendered as a safe string? then you can go with "Look & Talk"
- the `newString` will be user with `v-html` directive? then you should go with "Look &amp; Talk"

Aaron pointed that `&` is a logical operator in javascript, but this will only be a problem if you bind the value (`:newString` or `v-bind:newString`)

Comment: why just don't :var=" 'string' " (spaces are for readability) ?

Comment: @YosefSalmalian  if you have only the string I don't see any motive to bind it